# Соответствие числа в input количеству отображаемых строк

Tags: javascript

Задача: указанное в поле input цифровое значение должно автоматически создавать аналогичное количество строк.

```js
let out = document.getElementById('out');
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
input.value = +input.value;



const text = `
 <div class="row"></div>
`;

let row = document.createElement('div');
row.innerHTML = text;


document.body.appendChild(row);

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  out.innerHTML = this.value;
})

for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  return row + '<br>';
}
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<p id="out"></p>
```

Comment: у вас так и задумано `return` в цикле?

Comment: Ну да. return, только всё равно не получается ничего добавить...

Comment: Мой вариант: https://jsfiddle.net/alexseveneight/k9oeufzd/100/